# Getting error but don't know why

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

I've been trying to merge two image views together to save as one image, I've got this far however I'm now getting an error.

```
private View merge;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_take);
        merge = (View) findViewById(R.layout.camera_take);
    }

    public Bitmap combineImages(ImageView picPreview, ImageView spunkOverlay) {
        Bitmap cs = null;
        merge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        merge.buildDrawingCache(true);
        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(merge.getDrawingCache());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs);
        merge.draw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        merge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return cs;
    }
```

The error is:

```
02-14 20:09:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(8450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 20:09:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(8450): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 20:09:47.943: E/AndroidRuntime(8450):     at      com.test.test.Camera.combineImages(Camera.java:170)
```

line 170 is:

```
merge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: post your camera_take xml file.

Comment: when is combineImages called ?

Comment: There are answers already, but just to mention.. If you get a null pointer exception at a line that invokes a method on any object, in this case invoking the `setDrawingCacheEnabled()` on object `merge`, that means the object is null, and you cannot invoke any methods on null object, and hence you get Null Pointer Exception. These kind of errors can be interpreted using the error stack trace.

Comment: Ok so I gave my xml an id and found the view by using the id however all the imageviews within the xml are being collapsed and saved into one rather than the two in combineImages.

Answer (score 0):

Merge is null.  You have the id wrong, you shouldn't be searching for the layout id, but the view id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is here:

```
merge = (View) findViewById (R.layout.camera_take);
```

Are you certain that is returning anything?